# moving data entery to the following row

Tags: excel, vba

I am using form in excel to make date entry in Database excel sheet. my first row is in line 7. 1st date entered went in row 7. the 2nd form entry still went and replace the data in row 7 instead of going to row 8. i know i need to make the last row +1 but i don't get it
please if you can answer before closing the post and direct me to another post. i am new in VBA

```
Dim last_row As Long

last_row = database.Range("D1").Value + 7

database.Range("b" & last_row).Value = form.Range("C4").Value
database.Range("c" & last_row).Value = form.Range("C5").Value
database.Range("d" & last_row).Value = form.Range("C6").Value
database.Range("e" & last_row).Value = form.Range("C7").Value
database.Range("f" & last_row).Value = form.Range("C8").Value
database.Range("g" & last_row).Value = form.Range("C9").Value

form.Range("c4:c6").ClearContents

MsgBox "data has been submitted"
```

Comment: You must calculate `last_row` after each data input and you need to use the next row. `last_row = database.Range("D" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(XlUp).Rows.Count + 1`... Supposing that `database` is your sheet object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testLastRow()
 Dim last_row As Long, database As Worksheet, Form As Worksheet
   Set database = Worksheets("Your database worksheet")
   Set Form = Worksheets("Your Form worksheet")
   last_row = database.Range("D" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

  With database
    .Range("b" & last_row).value = Form.Range("C4").value
    .Range("c" & last_row).value = Form.Range("C5").value
    .Range("d" & last_row).value = Form.Range("C6").value
    .Range("e" & last_row).value = Form.Range("C7").value
    .Range("f" & last_row).value = Form.Range("C8").value
    .Range("g" & last_row).value = Form.Range("C9").value
 End With
 Form.Range("c4:c6").ClearContents

 MsgBox "data has been submitted"
End Sub
```

Comment: Now, it would be good to delete all the comments, except the first. I will delete mines...